# JQuery Event Binding within Event Listener

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a button that is supposed to remove an entry from my table. However, when I click on it, it sends multiple requests to the server. I have tried stopping the event from propagating and placing e.preventDefault() but it still sends multiple requests.

Is there something I can change to make this send once per request only?

```
$("#apiTableController").off("click").on("click", "#removeKey", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#confirmation-dialog").dialog("open");
    $("#confirmation-dialog").on("dialogclose", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if ($("#confirm-modal").val() == "true") {
            selected = apiTable.rows('.selected').data().toArray();
            var form_data = selected;
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("Remove", "ApiKey", new {area="Configuration"})",
                method: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(form_data),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (result) {
                    toastr.success("Access Removed");
                    apiTable.draw();
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    toastr.error(error.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});

<div id="apiTableController" class="pull-right bottom-margin">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="removeKey"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a `console.log()` entry to each event to see when each is firing? I suspect some other event is bubbling up and triggering it repeatedly.

Comment: It was the confirmation-dialog that needed to have an off

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out if I add a $("#confirmation-dialog").off("dialogclose").on("dialogclose"), it works properly?